# blender audio frequency detectionrange limit 1000000khz

Tags: animation, audio

i want to use blender to detect frequency, but it only has a limit, i need it to detect frequencies of upto penta herdz or above. no limit. the frequencies are usually used for audio visualization and audio spectrum.

Comment: An audio file can’t contain frequencies higher than half it’s sampling rate. So it’s hard to imagine where you are expecting to find petahertz frequencies.

Comment: Audio generally isn't considered to go above 20 kHz, you wrote 1000000khz which is 1 GHz, 1 petahertz is $10^{15}$ cycles per second and is an order of magnitude above gamma radiation?

Comment: there where it says, bake sounds to F-curves it goes up to  100 000 on highest frequency, excuse my mistake. i think if i get the frequencies of color, with python i could use the values to arrange them in a 3D environment, that should give me a view of the place where the microphones are placed. at 100 000 there is movement as i have tested it before. now i need sphere mesh to react to the frequencies of color. that way doctors can scan your body for things.